# How to make a regex pattern which compares the frequency of a group with another

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-group

The problem is to find the existence of a substring with `n` number of `a` and followed by `2 * n` number `b` and `n >= 1`. This is a very easy question to do but I want to know if there is any way to do this using regex only.

For example:

`zzaabbbbzz` should print in print `Yes`.

`zzaazzbbbbzz` should print `No`.

`zzaaabbbbzz` should print in `No`.

I tried in python 3 like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(a+)(b+)')
check = pattern.findall(input())
if(len(check)>0):
   for i in check:
     if(len(i[0])*2 == len(i[1])):
        print('Yes')
        break
   else:
     print('No')
else:
   print('No')
```

I want to know if there is any way to provide some count for a and b in regex pattern itself.

The question can be done using simple loop and manually checking each character and count `a` and `b` occurrences with `O(n)` complexity but I want to learn something new.

Help me to shorten this code?

Comment: For a known and preferrably low (<10) `n` it is possibly. Otherwise not as far as I know. I'd love to be proven wrong. By the way, do you think that "only regex" somehow improves the O() ?

Answer (score 1):

While this can't be done using only regex (regex can count deterministically, but can't compare quantities) your example's readability can be improved a bit:

```
import re

inputs = 'zzaabbbbzz', 'zzaazzbbbbzz', 'zzaaabbbbzz'
regex = re.compile(r'.*?(a+)(b+).*')
for inp in inputs:
    match = regex.match(inp)
    if match:
        a_count = len(match.group(1))
        b_count = len(match.group(2))
        if b_count == 2 * a_count:
            print('YES')
        else:
            print('NO')
    else:
        print('NO')
```

Outputs

```
YES
NO
NO
```